Laravel Backpack how to customize/overwrite form_save_buttons.blade.php just one controller?
I am trying to display all the save action button in company/create to be aligned as horizontally instead of drop down and keep all the other controller's form save buttons as normal/default

Action buttons are part of the create form.

You can copy the create view blade file & customize form_save_buttons there.
vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/create.blade.php
Next, set your custom view for that particular create operation.
$this->crud->setCreateView('path.to.your.view');

